# Python libraries for protocol dissection

Tags: network-programming, network-protocols

I am new to computer networking field.i don't have any idea regarding protocol dissector.But i wanted to create protocol dissector using python.since i know python language, if you mention the library that is  used in python to create protocol dissection it would be very helpful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There's no need to denigrate yourself; everyone is here for help about something they don't know. Also, be sure to phrase your question _as a question_, so readers know what you're actually asking. For future reference, [here's a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to write good questions.

Comment: It would also help a lot if you could define "protocol dissection", and give more concrete examples of the things you would like to be able to do. E.g. "How do I capture and decode TCP packet headers with Python?"

Comment: sir, i want to dissect the ip protocol? for that what library is useful?

Answer (score 2):

One library you could look at is [Scapy](https://scapy.net/):

> Scapy is a Python program that enables the user to send, sniff and dissect and forge network packets. This capability allows construction of tools that can probe, scan or attack networks.

Comment: It's good but it's way far from Wireshark's dissection.